# vertex-deletion and edge-deletion parameters

Tags: complexity-theory, classification, parameterized-complexity, upper-bound

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a graph class. For any class $\mathcal{H}$, we know that the minimal number of vertices that has to be removed from $G\in \mathcal{H}$ such that we get a graph from $\mathcal{G}$ is at most twice the number of edges that has to be removed from $G$ in order to obtain a graph from $\mathcal{G}$.

Example: The feedback vertex/edge set number ($\operatorname{fen}$ and $\operatorname{fvsn}$) correspond to $\mathcal{G}$ = forests and obviously $\operatorname{fvsn}\leq 2\operatorname{fen}$.

My question is, is there a (nontrivial) class of graphs $\mathcal{H}$ where $\operatorname{fen}\leq f(\operatorname{fvsn})$ for some function $f$? This is particularly for $\mathcal{G}=$forests. What if we pick a different $\mathcal{G}$?

Generalizing, is there a (nontrivial) class $\mathcal{H}$ such that for any class $\mathcal{G}$ and any $G\in \mathcal{H}$ the edge-deletion distance to $\mathcal{G}$ is bounded by a function of the vertex-deletion distance to $\mathcal{G}$?

Sorry if this turns out to be trivial.

E: As JimE pointed in the comments, we can create silly counterexamples and even the claim that vertex-deletion distance might not be twice the edge-deletion distance, let's assume that all considered graph classes are hereditary.

Comment: Do you have a cited source for your statement starting as "we know that the minimal number..."? I am not convinced this is true for non-hereditary graph classes. Do you mean to stipulate some properties on your graph classes?

Comment: Here's a silly example of what I mean: if the target graph class is the set of graphs where the number of vertices and the number of edges are **both** a multiple of 10, given a graph with 10 vertices and 11 edges, there is just one edge that could be deleted to delete into this class, while it would require the deletion of 10 vertices. I'm fairly sure some 'nontrivial' examples can be constructed as well, but maybe your statement is easily fixed if it is only meant to be within the scope of hereditary graph classes.

Comment: @JimN Well, if I have to remove $m$ edges to obtain a graph from $\mathcal{G}$, then certainly i have to remove at most $2m$ vertices to obtain a graph from $\mathcal{G}$.
E: Ah, I see what you mean, okay, that's a very silly example.

Comment: It's not hard to come up with more examples. Define a graph class of all graphs which have the property that each of its connected components of size at least 4 **contains** an induced $C_4$. Then upon an input graph of a large clique $K_n$, only 2 edges are required to be removed to create an induced $C_4$, while $n-3$ vertices would have to be removed in order to make this a connected component of size 3 (it is impossible to create a new induced substructure via vertex deletions).

Comment: I still don't understand your argument for the vertex bound. If the edges are obstructions to a property, deleting one of the two endpoints of that edge (not both endpoints) is enough to remove all those edge obstructions.